# Our custom OBD II reader when plugged in drops engine rpm to 0 along with turning on engine check light

Tags: obd-ii, truck, obd

We are a small startup who are trying to develop their own obd2 reader. We were able to get live rpm reading from our car but when the same device was plugged into an Eicher truck (BS 6 Engine) the truck is stopping. Once our obd is removed the truck is able to resume its operations again.

Can anyone explain the reason behind this? Is Eicher not allowing us to connect to 3rd party obd reader or do we need to check out a few things such as communication protocol or any other? As we thought that if we are able to read the rpm data from our car the same would work in the truck but clearly we were wrong.

Kindly guide us.

Tested Successfully in our vehicle: Mahindra Scorpio N
Year: 2022

Truck Model Name : Eicher Pro 8035XM
Year: 2022

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! In order for us to help you, we'd need the pin out you're using for your OBD2 reader, then what vehicle you first tried it on (include year/make/model). We'd also need the year of the Eicher truck. The engine most likely has nothing to do with your issue.  Most likely, you're causing a short to the ECU on the Eicher truck, which is not allowing it to process, but who knows.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your prompt response. I have updated the truck details. Also is this a possibility that the same obd works fine in a car but shorts the ECU in a truck? Are the architectures different for both?

Comment: Depending on what you used to setup your OBDII pinout, yes it could be different.

Comment: As already asked, what is the year/make/model of the "car" used originally?

Comment: I have updated the details

Comment: As a startup, do you have wiring diagrams of the Eicher's OBDII port to compare with your OBDII scantool? Many pins are used for the various comms, and you'd need to know which ones are needed for truck application. If you have wiring diagrams then you can determine which wires are mismatched to the Eicher, disabling the engine. You can also experiment by disconnecting one OBDII reader wire to see which wire allows engine running.

Comment: Trucks usually have 24V board systems (as opposed to 12V), is your OBD2 reader circuit prepared for that?